# Is there way to fix this with datatype strings? [R programming]

Tags: r, string

I need to change the datatype of 80 columns in 8 dataframes continously before I can merge them later on. The 10 columns are always the same name and will be the same datatype (as.factor, as.factor, as.numeric, as.numeric, as.numeric, as.numeric, as.numeric, as.numeric, as.numeric, as.numeric).
I could not get this to work in a string that I apply that string to the dataframe. That will safe me like 60 rows of work every week I need to do this.

Hope you guys understand the issue and can help me out ;)

Comment: Can you give some more information about your data? Preferrably a minimal reproducible example with your input and desired output.

Comment: str(X30_omzet$Zondag)
 chr [1:185] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA "7" "ZO" NA "1.89" "3.72" NA "42.24" "1.86" "3.86" "4.18" "7.13" "6.03" "15.24" "1.99" "0" "6.58" NA "6.38" "17.13" "15.16" "0" ...

I need to use these character columns to be numeric so I could do calculations with them

Comment: Have you tried with `as.numeric()`?

Comment: Yeah it works when I do as.factor, as.numeric. But it takes a total of 200 rows to do it for all the columns. I wondered if there is a easy way to do it in like 1 line of command for each dataset.

Comment: If you know the names and your desired type, you can type it out in a function to do it for you. Either explictly (you give the names), or conditionally (you make a function to find the column by a condition).